# Jquery Ajax --- "Error Has Occured During Processing - Undefined"

Tags: c#, jquery

I have a Jquery Ajax Function as below

```
var items = [];

var LoginObj = new Object();
LoginObj.UserName = $("#txtUserName").val();
LoginObj.Password = $("#txtPassword").val();

items.push(LoginObj);
var LoginObj = new Object();
LoginObj.UserName = $("#txtUserName").val();
LoginObj.Password = $("#txtPassword").val();

items.push(LoginObj);
//Define DTO i.e. Data Transfer Object as follows
var DTO = { 'userLogin': items };

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "Login.asmx/CheckLogin",
```

Am calling a Webservice Method from Ajax were i have written my C# code. Am sending an Array in jquery and expecting a LIST in C#. Everyting Works fine.

I remove List in my C# code and just have a Dummy Class which would eventually fail to receive. But my doubt even before the Server side function is called am getting Error saying  **"Error Has Occured During Processing - Undefined"**.

My doubt is How Client knows the Error even before server side is called ? I kept a breakpoint in c# which never got HIT. If i change that class to a list and everything fine

Thanks

Comment: Um... Where's there rest of your code? Fiddler or firebug net panel might help you understand what's going on.

Comment: "If i change that class to a list and everything fine", You change something in the serverside code and everything is fine, then that indicates the problem is perhaps server side?

Comment: show us your c# code and your Dummy class, and your full ajax call